# Brightness of a lightbulb if a different voltage source is used

Tags: voltage, power, circuit-analysis

A question that I came across was the following:

A standard light bulb in the U.S is 60W. The standard wall outlet voltage in the U.S is 120V, but in Europe, the standard wall outlet voltage is 240V. If this 60W bulb could be plugged into a socket in Europe, what would be true about how bright the bulb was?

The answer is apparently the bulb would be 4 times as bright as the power would quadruple

So it is clear to me that the power from the bulb will change as P = V<sup>2</sup>/R.

My question/concept I need clarified is that if this 60W bulb is plugged into a 240V socket, it will no longer be 60W right?

If this is the case why are bulbs rated for example 75W? or 120W? if the power depends on what the voltage source would be, wouldn't the power always change?

Additionally, does doubling the power or tripling the power always imply that the brightness has doubled or tripled respectively?

Comment: It being a 60W light bulb is short hand for it being *rated* as a 60W light bulb.

Comment: Re: "4 times as bright." If we make the simplifying assumption that the resistance would not change too much because of the increased temperature, then the bulb would dissipate four times as much _power._ At least, it would until it burned out. But, the relationship between electrical power and brightness might not be as simple as you think. It depends on, among other things, what you actually mean when you say "brightness."  There are quite a [lot of different ways to measure light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photometry_(optics)).

Comment: @DKNguyen More specifically rated as a 60W light bulb **at the specified voltage**. A 60W 120V light is quite different than a 60W 240V light.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is kind of a dubious textbook-style question that you have unfortunately been given, and unfortunately you may have to just give them what they want for it to be considered 'correct'.

Real lamps do not behave in such a simple manner. The resistance increases with voltage (because the temperature increases). The light output increases and the color spectrum shifts from reddish to blueish as the element gets hotter. At lower voltages the incandescent bulb may give off no *visible* light (but plenty of IR) and still consume plenty of power.

Below is a graph from [here](http://www.lamptech.co.uk/Documents/IN%20Voltage.htm) indicating the typical behavior of one type of an  incandescent bulb.

[image]

As you can see only a 20% increase in voltage leads to a 30% increase in power (not 44% as you might expect, because the ohms increase), the life is reduced to less than 1/10 of nominal, but the lumens increase by 80% (not by the 30% you might expect if efficiency in lumens/watt remained constant).

The design of incandescent bulbs is a trade-off between lifetime and efficiency. They are quite a bit more efficient if you run the filament hotter than nominal, but the lifetime decreases drastically. Similarly, by running the bulb (of a given design) at lower voltage the lifetime can be increased drastically however you get a lot fewer lumens per unit of energy consumed.

If you actually connect a 120VAC bulb to 240VAC it will last only a few seconds or minutes (I vaguely recall having performed the experiment and it lasted longer than I expected).

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things.

- Whether brightness is directly proportional to power depends on how you define brightness. If you mean total radiated energy, then yes, it is proportional to power. If you mean total *visible* radiated energy (ignoring anything IR and UV), then it's not proportional to power, the relationship is more complicated.
- Incandescent lightbulbs do not have a fixed resistance; in fact, their resistance changes quite a lot as they heat up. Since self-heating is how they *work*, changing the voltage will cause a change in temperature, which will also change the bulb's resistance. Thus, in a case like this where thermal effects can't be ignored, steady-state power is not directly proportional to voltage squared, as it would be in a constant-temperature (or zero-tempco) resistor.
- Lightbulbs are made for use at a specific voltage. Thus, labelling a bulb sold in the US as 60 watts means it will draw 60 watts from an American light socket. If a lightbulb sold in Europe was sold as 60 watts, that means it would draw 60 watts from a European light socket. (The number is approximate, as the exact voltage varies over time and location, but it's close enough.)
- A light bulb made for use on 120 V mains would immediately break if connected to 230 V, and a lightbulb made for use on 230 V mains would barely glow on 120 V.

Answer (score 1):

> *why are bulbs rated for example 75W? or 120W? if the power depends on
> what the voltage source would be, wouldn't the power always change?*

Lightbulbs are designed for their appropriate rated supply voltage and, at that rated supply voltage the lightbulb power is stated. So, you need to know the voltage and the power tells you how many watts it consumes at that voltage.

> *If this 60W <s>battery</s> lightbulb could be plugged into a socket in Europe, what
> would be true about how bright the bulb was?*

It would be very bright (4 times the power approximately) for a fraction of a second then it would fuse and go open circuit thus producing zero brightness.

> *Additionally, does doubling the power or tripling the power always
> imply that the brightness has doubled or tripled respectively?*

If the lightbulb could survive this event then no, because the lamp resistance would also increase as it got hotter and this would limit power somewhat. Brightness is also a human perception thing so that needs to be factored in.